# Prove that $h:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n $ (not necessarily linear) can be written uniquely of the form $h(x) = \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i (x) a_i,$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, isometry

In the book of *Analysis on Manifolds* by Munkres, at page 175, it is given that

> Let $h:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n $ be a map s.t $h(0) = 0$. [...]
>   Assume that $h$ is an isometry with $h(e_i) = a_i$ for all $i$.Then
>   for each $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $h(x)$ can be written uniquely in the
>   form  $$h(x) = \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i (x) a_i,$$ for certain
>   real-valued functions $\alpha_i (x)$ of $x$.

However he does not give any justification for the existence & uniqueness of **the functions** $\alpha_i$s, so my question is that

**How can we show the existence and the uniqueness of $\alpha_i$s (the functions)?**

Comment: This is just the fact that the $a_i$ are a basis of $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: @GEdgar Well,... that .. make sense actually. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @GEdgar If you post your comment as an answer, I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just the fact that the $a_i$ are a basis of $\mathbb R^n$.  For that you can use the "isometry" property.